# MP3 not playing back after converting to base64 and downloading

Tags: c#, android, json, cordova, audio

I am having problems playing back recorded audio from a mobile device

Project details:
Mobile App collecting data, syncing to management interface with API

Mobile (cordova)
-Records audio/mp3 files on device and submits to API as base64 string

API (C#/.NET)
-Accepts JSON request object with base64 string data as audio
-converts to byte array and stores MP3 in Azure Blob storage

When I **DO** play back the MP3 via the browser data-url, if I download the file locally and try to play it back with Windows Media or VLC, the file won't play.

Because of this, I don't think my issue is due to the converting of the base64 string to audio...but I am including some snippets of code for reference...

Here is some snippets of code that I'm using to convert...but I suspect something is happening on the mobile side???

As the API accepts a JSON object, the MP3 data is passed in the requestObject.AudioData attribute as a base64 string

```
// Create the blob client.CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureDirectory"]);
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(requestObject.AudioFileName);

//convert Base64 string to ByteArray to send to the Blob storage..
byte[] tbmBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(requestObject.AudioData);
blockBlob.UploadFromByteArray(tbmBytes, 0, tbmBytes.Length);

//all is good...file gets uploaded and can be accessed via Blob Storage in Azure
```